# poles and geometric series

Tags: complex-analysis

I am having trouble understanding how to find the poles of a function. I feel like I understand what a pole is but I am not sure about the order of the pole.

I think the reason I struggle to find poles is because I do not have a good understanding of geometric series. Are there different geometric series? If so, how do I know when to use them?

> For example, $$\int_{C}{\frac{e^{z}}{(z^{2}+\pi^{2})^{2}}}dz,$$
> $C:|z|=4$
>
> How would I go about finding the poles and their order?

Even if I do not need geometric series to solve this could someone please still explain them to me?

Comment: $a^2+b^2=(a+bi)(a-bi)$. Poles occur when denominator is zero. Look at the exponent associated with the pole to get order, ex. $1/x^2$ has a pole at $x=0$ of order 2.

Comment: You can see Poles at $\pm i\pi$ [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ComplexPlot%5B1%2F%28z%5E2%2BPi%5E2%29%5E2%2C%7Bz%2C-4-4I%2C4%2B4I%7D%5D)

Comment: It looks like you reposted this question. I answered the repost, and will copy that answer here. You should delete the repost.

Comment: @C.Moore Sorry i didn't mean for it too look like a repost. In the other post I was actually just trying to figure out how we can determine if the pole is in the circle, but I think you answered that below! Thanks!

Comment: No worries, I think I see what you mean.

Comment: As for answers, I like what @saulspatz wrote because he actually used the residue theorem. It is much more complete.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it's clear that the function is analytic when the denominator doesn't vanish, so the only places there could possibly be poles are $z=\pm\pi i$.  We know that $e^z$ never vanishes, so these are indeed poles.

Take $p=\pi i$.  Since the numerator doesn't vanish, we need only be concerned with the denominator.  For the denominator, we have $$\begin{align}
z^2+\pi^2&=(z-\pi i)^2+2\pi i(z-\pi i)\\
&=(z-\pi i)(z-\pi i +2\pi i)\\
&=(z-\pi i)2\pi i\left(1+\frac{z-\pi i}{2\pi i}\right)
\end{align}$$ so that $$\left(z^2+\pi^2\right)^{-2}=\frac{-1}{4\pi^2}(z-\pi i)^{-2}\left(1+\frac{z-\pi i}{2\pi i}\right)^{-2}\tag1$$

Now, by the the binomial formula, $$\left(1+\frac{z-\pi i}{2\pi i}\right)^{-2}= 1 - \frac{z-\pi i}{\pi i}+\text{higher order terms}$$ and we see that the leading term in the Laurent expansion has degree $-2$ so that $\pi i$ is a pole of order $2$.

For a pole of order $2$ we have the [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_(complex_analysis)#Limit_formula_for_higher-order_poles) $$\operatorname{Res}_{z=\pi i} f(z)=\lim_{z\to\pi i}\frac d{dz}\left(f(z)(z-\pi i)^2\right),$$ where $f(z)$ is the integrand.  From $(1)$,
$$\operatorname{Res}_{z=\pi i} f(z)=\lim_{z\to\pi i} \frac d{dz}\frac{-e^z}{4\pi ^2}\left(1+\frac{z-\pi i}{2\pi i}\right)^{-2}$$

Take it from here.

Answer (score 1):

In the case you're citing there, $\int_C \frac{e^z}{(z^2+\pi^2)^2}dz$, you have to factor the denominator to find the roots of the polynomial. So since $(z^2+\pi^2)^2 = (z-i\pi)^2(z+i\pi)^2$ we see the poles of $f(z)$ are $\pm i\pi$, and these poles have multiplicity 2. Since your circle has radius $4$ and $|i\pi|=\pi<4$ your poles are inside the contour. In general, you just have to find where the poles are (e.g. by factoring like above) and then, if your contour is a circle, seeing if the distance between the pole and the center of your circle is less than the radius.

I should warn that in this case you still need to find the residues at $\pm i\pi$ to evaluate the integral. Factoring is just the first step.

Comment: "seeing if the distance between the pole and the center of your circle is less than the radius." Is rhis how we determine if the pole is inside the circle?

Comment: That's exactly right. The interior of the circle is this set of points.